# JSP page not populating the formBean property associated with <html:select> <html:option>

Tags: java, jsp, struts

```
<html:select property="fileLocation">
  <%
    ArrayList uploadLocationLookUp = null;
    uploadLocationLookUp = (ArrayList) request.getSession().getAttribute("uploadLocation");
    if (uploadLocationLookUp.size() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < uploadLocationLookUp.size(); i++) {
            LookUpBean lookUpBeanItems = (LookUpBean) uploadLocationLookUp.get(i);
  %>
    <html:option value="<%=lookUpBeanItems.getLookUpCode()%>">
      <%= lookUpBeanItems.getLookUpCode() %>
    </html:option>
  <% }} %>
</html:select>
```

I'm using the LookUpBean to populate the options in the select tag which is associated with a formBean with property fileLocation.

While all other properties are populating property in the formBean this one is not. I also tried getting to it using request.getParameter("fileLocation") in my action class but it just wont work.

Can anyone eyeball this chunk of code and point out any silly mistake that might have been missed? Are there other areas/issues that I might have run into? A quick response would be much appriciated. Thanks

---

It worked :)
Don't know why though :(

All I did was refactor my code and rearranged the input elements on my form. Once I placed the rogue `<html:select>` after a piece of java code on my jsp, it worked like a charm. Can anyone give pointers to something wrong that I did and why it worked after I rearranged my form elements?

Comment: Does the `ActionForm` contain a `fileLocation` property? Is the tag rendering as expected?

Comment: @Dave: fileLocation property is there in the ActionForm. The tag is rendered correctly. No clue where I'm wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with this code, provided that both the `fileLocation` and `lookUpCode` properties are Strings.

One tip, you should be able to eliminate the scriptlet code by using the [html:options](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#options) tag:

```
<html:select property="fileLocation">
    <html:options collection="uploadLocation" property="lookUpCode" labelProperty=""lookUpCode"/>
</html:select>
```

Comment: Tried the `<html:options>` too. The html is rendered correctly, request/FormBean still does not get any value.

Comment: What surprises me is that all other properties from that form are properly passed.